# Passing variable from input box to PHP script that calls to SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some issues with passing information from a form to a PHP script which then requests data from MySQL.

I get get data to return as long as I hard code the request; however, I'm trying to do it so when a user selects an option from the drop-down list to have it the runs the selected query. This is what I have in my form.

```
<form action="FETCH.PHP" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="mySelect">
<option value="South Yorkshire">South Yorkshire</option>
<option value="West Midlands">West Midlands</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

and this is what I have in my PHP script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*******","*******","*******","*******");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$selectedOption = $_POST["mySelect"];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` ='$_POST'");

echo "<div id=Results>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class=ClubName>";
echo $row['EstName'];
echo "<div class=Location>";
echo $row['EstAddress2'];
echo "<br>";
}
echo date("Y") . " " ."Search is Powered by PHP.";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I know there's something wrong here but I don't know what. This is the first time I have attempted anything with MySQL and PHP.

The current script does not give any errors but doesn't bring back any results. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies i wasn't shouting i just forgot to turn caps lock off and then couldn't be bothered to re-write it

Comment: Your query looks wrong WHERE  `EstProv` ='$_POST'");

Comment: -1 for the "couldn't be bothered" bit. Despite this, I've tidied up your question.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Thank you Chetan Paliwal your answer has worked for me :)

Comment: @Quentin I have had a lot of people mention that im completely new to SQL so i have no idea how it works. On the plus side tho the database only holds establishment names and location so there's no valuable data

Comment: @MrBBates: don't forget to tick the answer that most helped you. Read them all! And, as per the above, please take care to write questions carefully; not only do some questions create edit work, but enough of them can stop you asking future questions too (via a block on your account).

Comment: @MrBBates - this thread may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721786/how-does-sql-injection-work-and-how-do-i-protect-against-it

Comment: @MrBBates — Well, if you don't mind random visitors to your website being able to replace all your establishment names with swear words…

Comment: Quentin how can they do that? There's no insert commands etc int he PHP so i didn't think it would give them access to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in lies the problem:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` ='$_POST'");
```

Change that line to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` ='$selectedOption'");
```

---

**Update**

You should bind params to secure your script like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
    sprintf("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` = '%s'",
        preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $selectedOption))); // pattern based on your html select options
```

OR...

Do it the Object Orientated way: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I have added the update section in as you stated above. Thank you for your indepth answer

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE  `EstProv` ='$selectedOption'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This worked perfectly the only reason why i selected a different answer is because they provided more information however your answer was equally good

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL, you put the whole $_POST in, and for displaying the results, there is no close div tag.

Comment: Yep... and the div items don't have quote marks around the attribute values, so the result is invalid HTML.

Comment: @halfer i tried to add the " but it seems to break the PHP request with them in that was my next stage because i want to use CSS to style the results

Comment: @MrBBates: you can use single quotes instead (they are equally valid) or precede double-quotes with a backslash to "escape" them. For the latter, something like this: `echo "<div class=\"ClubName\">";`

Comment: @halfer thank you very much for that one saves me looking it up :)